# Creating a multiple user countdown counter (Python)

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction of a basic script.

This is for a game I created and wanted to create a countdown script to go along with it.

I want be able to have 4 users in which the program will first will ask for their name. After that each user will take turns entering their score starting at 100 and decreasing based on their input.  Once they hit zero they win. Once the first person hits 0 the others will have a chance to as well until the end of the round. Each 4 inputs will be considered 1 round.

There will be a lot more to the game but I just need the start.  I am new to Python but the easiest way for me to learn is to start off on a working script

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use `time.sleep(..)`.

Comment: It seems as though you are very new to python. You should probably start with an easier project.

Comment: I do state that I am new to python.  This is the best way for me to learn, hence why I picked form what I believe to be a simple project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import cmd

number_users = 4
number_rounds = 10  # or whatever
user_names = [None]*number_users
user_scores = [None]*number_users

for i in range(number_users):
    print("Enter name for user #{}: ".format(i+1))
    user_names[i] = input()
    user_scores[i] = 100

for round_number in range(number_rounds):
    print(" --- ROUND {} ---".format(round_number+1))
    for i in range(number_users):
        print("{}, Enter your score: ".format(user_names[i]))
        user_scores[i] = input()
    print("--- Scores for Round {} ---".format(round_number+1))
    for i in range(number_users):
        print("{} : {}".format(user_names[i], user_scores[i]))

print("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you!  There are a few differences but I can definitely work off of that.

Comment: You're Welcome - feel free to mark this answer as useful!